# Spring Batch - how to execute a specific step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I've developed a Spring Batch with 10 Step.
How can i execute a specific Step ?

My wish is to passed in JobParameter the Step to execute.
Only the Step specified in JobParameter must be executed.

I searched to use the Decider, but i'm not really satisfied.
There's a better Solution ?

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

cordially

Comment: I doubt you can do it, I think Your only hope is Decider.

Comment: Hi, yes, the solution is the decider. I finally used it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Decider is the correct option for the type of processing you're talking about.  I'd be interested in why you were "not really satisfied" by that option?

Comment: Hi, after differents tests, i finally used the decider. It is not so bad and do the job, i've used it in bad way in other dev.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar use case. I wanted to pass job name and step name as the input and expectation was to execute only that particular step from the job.

I created a Rest API which accepts job name and step name as URL parameters.
Below is the code inside the Rest API. It requires few objects injected into the class.

jobRegistry - instance of MapJobRegistry

jobRepository - instance of jobRepository

jobLauncher - instance of JobLauncher

```
    Job job = null;
    Step step = null;
    try{
       Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName);
       if(job instanceof StepLocator){
           Step = ((StepLocator)job).getStep(stepName);
       }
    }catch(NoSuchJobException ex){ 
          throw new Exception("Invalid Job", ex);
    }catch(NoSuchStepException ex){ 
          throw new Exception("Invalid Step", ex);
    }

    if(null == step){
        throw new Exception("invalid step");
    }

    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilder = new JobBuiderFactory(jobRepository);
    Job newJob = jobBuilder.get("specific-step-job")
                 .start(step)
                 .build();
    jobLauncher.run(newJob, jobParameters); //jobParameters relevant for this job
```

This will dynamically create a new job with name "specific-step-job" and add the specific step instance as the start/only step inside the new Job and executes this job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can test an individual step using [JobLauncherTestUtils#launchStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html#launchStep%28java.lang.String%29).

Please have a look at section [10.3. Testing Individual Steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/)

Find a sample code here [Spring Batch unit test example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-unit-test-example/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's interesting ! but my problem were to know how to execute a unique step and not testing. But i keep your link in mind. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to launch an individual step in spring batch but you can do it using `JobLauncherTestUtils` if possible.